# No se queda seleccionado visualmente el seleccionado

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

El siguiente formulario es un selector de idioma con el botón oculto (ya que es para un menú superior de una web). El botón se pulsa y ejecuta el formulario por javascript en cuanto es seleccionada la opción, eso funciona perfecto. **Pero ocurre que visualmente no se queda esa misma opción, sino siempre la misma.**

**HTML:**

```
 <form action="/i18n/setlang/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
              <input name="next" type="hidden" value="/" />
                <select class="form-select" name="language" onchange="changeLanguage()">
                  {% for lang in LANGUAGES %}
                    <option value="{{ lang.1 }}" style="min-width:100px" class="">{{ lang.1 }}</option>
                  {% endfor %}
                </select>
              <input name="sendChangeLanguage" id="sendChangeLanguage" class="form-control" type="submit" value="Go" style="display:none;" />
            </form>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script>
    function changeLanguage() {
      var selectButton = document.getElementById( 'sendChangeLanguage' );
      selectButton.click();
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: Después del request se va a reiniciar el select, es normal. Tenes que hacer un chequeo en la etiqueta `option` que compare el idioma actual con `lang` y si da `true` que agregue el atributo `selected`

Answer (score 0):

Lo que te falta es la propiedad selected en la opciónes ejemplo:

```
<select class="form-select" name="language" onchange="changeLanguage()">
  {% for lang in LANGUAGES %}
    <option value="{{ lang.1 }}" {% if lang.1 == <variable del lenguaje seleccionado> %}selected{% endif %} style="min-width:100px" class="">{{ lang.1 }}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

La solución fue la siguiente:
Al hacer la comparación lang.1 estaba en mayúsculas y LANGUAGE_CODE en minúsculas. Entonces al convertirlos en lower, sí que se da la condición por ejemplo de que if 'es' == 'es'

{% if lang.1|**lower** == LANGUAGE_CODE|**lower** %}

HTML:

```
<form action="/i18n/setlang/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
              <input name="next" type="hidden" value="/" />
                <select class="form-select" name="language" onchange="changeLanguage()">
                  {% for lang in LANGUAGES %}
                    {% if lang.1|lower == LANGUAGE_CODE|lower %}
                    <option value="{{ lang.1 }}" selected style="min-width:100px" class="">{{ lang.1 }}</option>
                    {% else %}
                    agur
                    <option value="{{ lang.1 }}" style="min-width:100px" class="">{{ lang.1 }}</option>
                    {% endif %}
                  {% endfor %}
                </select>
              <input name="sendChangeLanguage" id="sendChangeLanguage" class="form-control" type="submit" value="Go" style="display:none;" />
            </form>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
 <script>
    function changeLanguage() {
      var selectButton = document.getElementById( 'sendChangeLanguage' );
      selectButton.click();
    }
  </script>
```